# if clause return more than one row

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I need to get data from my table using if clause, here's an example of what I'm trying to do;

```
select if (condition='example',
(/*query1(return more than one row)*/),
(/*query2(return more than one row)*/) as data from table1 where iduser='1'
```

my complete query:

```
SELECT 
if(bagian='DOKTER',
(SELECT b.ruper
from bsl_ruang b 
join mr_ranap_dokter d 
on (b.noregis=d.noregis) 
where d.dokter = '999999'),
(SELECT u.nama 
FROM m_unit u 
join muser_tdinas t 
on(t.unit=u.unit) 
where id_user = '999999')) as ruper 
FROM `muser` where id_user = '999999'
```

my tables;

```
bsl_ruang                    mr_ranap_dokter       
++========++======++         ++========++========++
||noregis ||ruper ||         ||dokter  ||noregis ||
++========++======++         ++========++========++
||10000000||ruper1||         ||9999999 ||10000000||
||10000001||ruper2||         ||9999999 ||10000001||
++========++======++         ++========++========++

m_unit                       muser_tdinas                  m_user
++========++======++         ++========++========++        ++========++=======++
||unit    ||nama  ||         ||id_user ||unit    ||        ||id_user ||bagian ||
++========++======++         ++========++========++        ++========++=======++
||00001   ||ruper1||         ||8888888 ||00001   ||        ||9999999 ||DOKTER ||
||00002   ||ruper2||         ||8888888 ||00002   ||        ||8888888 ||PERAWAT||
++========++======++         ++========++========++        ++========++=======++
```

**SUMMARY**

so `if bagian=dokter`, it will join table `bsl_ruang` and `mr_ranap_dokter` and get `ruper`

and `if bagian=perawat`, it will join table `m_unit` and `muser_tdinas` and get `nama`

but if clause can only return one data, is there any other way to do this? note that I can't change my database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this is not the best solution but I decided to use a procedure for my problem, here's my procedure;

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `GetRuperRanap`(lIdUser Varchar(12))
BEGIN
     Declare lBagian VarChar(20);
     SELECT bagian into lBagian FROM `muser` where id_user = lIdUser;
     if lBagian='DOKTER' then
         SELECT distinct b.ruper as ruper from bsl_ruang b join mr_ranap_dokter d on (b.noregis=d.noregis) where d.dokter = lIdUser;
     else
         SELECT u.nama as ruper FROM m_unit u join muser_tdinas t on(t.unit=u.unit) where id_user = lIdUser;
     end if;
END;
```

and I just need to call it on query, hope it help